# Jquery Countdown on finish Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This plugin will show real time countdown which will show on the webpage.

I read documentation **on.finish callback** on the **Official website**.

What I try to do is that if the timer **finish counting**, it will **hide** span#limit.

**This is the link:**

http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html

**This is my Code :**

**HTML :**

```
<span id="limit">
    <input type="hidden" name="limit" value="<?php echo $dataproduct['limit']; ?>" />
</span>
```

**jQuery :**

```
var data = $("input[name=limit]").val();

    $("#limit").countdown(data, function(event) {
    $(this).text(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
       .on('finish.countdown', function() {
           $(this).hide();
       )};
    });
```

it will show countdown like this on the webpage :

**01 days 19:40:00**

until

**00 days 00:00:00**

The problem was this span **did not hide** just like I try to do.

What's wrong with my code? Callback? Wrong syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this : As per doucument you have provide, you need to call `.on('finish.countdown'` after closing bracket of `.countdown()` function. And your code will work as expected.

```
 var data = $("input[name=limit]").val();

   $("#limit").countdown("2015-07-02 19:40:00", function(event)                        
   {
       $(this).text(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));

    }).on('finish.countdown', function() {
           $(this).hide();
    });
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x9fL0ohm/1/)**

**NOTE:** Please change the date input as per your convinient so that you can see countdown to become zero in short time.

Comment: Thanks Bhushan Kawadkar for answering, after i put your method, nothing show on the span#limit. no more showing 01 days 19:40:00. what's wrong with my code?

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle link with you problem statement?

Comment: but in fiddle link `.on('finish.countdown`.. is missing and when i put that nothing working. Can you reproduce your original issue in jsfiddle with code posted.

Comment: yeah, when i put .on('finish.countdown") it will show nothing. btw, this method i got from, http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html

Comment: I went through document and found that you need to call finish callback just after `countdown` function call and not inside it. Please check my answer and jsfiddle. Don't forget to change the time near to your local time so that you can see countdown to zero.

Comment: Omg! Thank you very much  Bhushan Kawadkar, I want to increase ur reputation but it seem like not working. i dont know why,                                       YOU SAVE MY LIFE TONIGHT!

Comment: happy to help you :). No worries.. I think you need sufficient reputation count to vote me.