# How to change class in jquery for a countdown timer when it is zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

In bootstrap i have used a jquery countdown plugin i need to change my class from label-default to lable-danger when time equals to 00 weeks 00 days 00:00:00

```
<!--this element class i want to change--> 

<span id="sp-dt-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="label label-default"></span>

<!--This is my countdown plugin-->
<script type="text/javascript">  
     $('#sp-dt-<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>').countdown('<?php echo $expDate; ?>', function(event) {$(this).html(event.strftime('%w weeks %d days %H:%M:%S'));
 });
```

**[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnNsw.png)**

As u can see in the picture when time comes to 00 weeks 00 days 00:00:00  i want to change class from label-dafault to label-danger

Note :

- I have used `getElementById` but the `jquery` file of countdown and
  `jquery CDN` are conflicting hence giving "Uncaught error".
- I was also trying to use `$('#sp-dt-<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>').val()
  = 00 weeks 00 days 00:00:00` but it is not working

Comment: Try `$('#sp-dt-<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>').text()== "00 weeks 00 days 00:00:00"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Countdown on finish Callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182732/jquery-countdown-on-finish-callback)

Comment: What countdown plugin are you using?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1  can u help me with this error

Comment: i removed everything still it shows the same there is no ' ) in my query and did all possibilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code

```
$('#sp-dt-<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>').countdown('<?php echo $expDate; ?>', function(event) 
    {
        $(this).html(event.strftime('%w weeks %d days %H:%M:%S'));
        //if remaining days are less then 4 weeks = 7*4 = 28 days
        if (event.strftime('%D') <= 28 && event.strftime('%m') == 0 && event.strftime('%Y') == 0) {
                  $(this).addClass("four-weeks-remaining");
            }
    }).on('finish.countdown', function() {
           $(this).addClass("new-class");
    });
```

Comment: bro its giving an error  : A non well formed numeric value encountered in

Comment: thanks a lot bro but your finish,countdown is not working

Comment: What is it showing in error? I did tested it... it is working.. Play with code for some time... try different things.

Comment: There would be right mark by my answer. Below up, down vote links.

Comment: @tahaDhailey I think my answer was more appropriate.... and dynamic.... So, you should have marked answer as correct which worked better for you.

Comment: Haha... thanks.... I think you should post one question on how does stackoverflow works.. ;) #kidding

Comment: i will loose my reputation and even badges on that LOL

Answer (score 0):

You can add this javascript to your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        $('.label-default').each(function(){
            if ( $(this).text() == '00 weeks 00 days 00:00:00'){
                $(this).addClass('label-danger').removeClass('label-default');
            }
        });

    }); //END document.ready
</script>
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/h795br40/)</kbd>

Comment: You should accept an answer to this question -- it was answered, and the solution does what you asked. Then, post a new question asking for help with that extra bit. Instead of one or two people (me and Mayur) trying to help with the new question, you will have dozens of new people reading the question and trying to help - just within the first half hour!. And if new readers learn something from your question, you will be upvoted also.

Comment: is it a compliment or criticism coz i am very naive to stackoverflow??